# Probability of an event happening with known success rate

Tags: probability

Consider a soccer game.

The probability that player A gets an opportunity to attempt a goal shot is 0.02, and their success rate (of scoring, given that opportunity) is 0.45. I also have similar information for players B and C.

I am trying to calculate what the probability is that all three players scores, or none of them, or only one, etc.

Are my computations below correct?

- P(all events end with a goal) = P(A)P(success of A) + P(B)P(success of B) + P(C)P(success of C)
- P(no event ends with a goal) = P(A)P(1 - success of A) + P(B)P(1 - success of B) + P(C)P(1 - success of C)

Comment: the first thing that you need to know is; if these events are independent or not, although you can formulate the problem without this knowledge. One more thing: check if your sum of probabilities will eventually add up to $1$ (at maximum), since it is a probability right?

Comment: The events are independent. I have very small probabilities, so they add up to 1, but what is your opinion on the formulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think
$$P(\text{all events end with a goal}) = P(A)\cdot P(\text{success of A})\cdot P(B)\cdot P(\text{success of B})\cdot P(C)\cdot P(\text{success of C})$$
$$P(\text{no events end with a goal}) = P(A)\cdot (1-P(\text{success of A}))\cdot P(B)\cdot (1-P(\text{success of B}) )\cdot P(C)\cdot (1-P(\text{success of C}))$$
if they are independent.

Comment: Yes, the events are independent. Can you reason some more on your answer, and also what is your opinion on the first one (all events end with a goal)? Thanks

Comment: In probability theory if two events, A and B, are independent,the probability that they both occur is equal to the product of the probabilities of the two individual events $P(A\bigcap B)=P(A)P(B)$ in your case since all events have to occur to have goal in all three cases then it must be the product of them. In no goal case chance A should happen but no goal should be scored, similarly with chance B and C.

Comment: use \text environment